# Laravel 5.3 parse variable from controller to blade view not working

Tags: laravel, variables, controller, laravel-blade

I cannot seed my blade with variables from my controller.

Look at my controller:

```
public function formAdd()
{
  return view('restaurant.categoryAdd')->with(['myvar' => 'xxx']);
}
```

In my view categoryAdd:

```
{{$myvar}}
```

This way, I got a 500 error. But if I change my view to:

```
@if (isset($myvar))
<p>Success!</p>
@endif
```

There is not 500 error, the page is ok, but the 'Success!' is not returned. It means $myvar is undefined. I tested various codes, but I still cannot seed my view.

I tried:

```
return view('restaurant.categoryAdd')->with(['myvar' => 'xxx']);

return view('restaurant.categoryAdd')->with('myvar', 'xxx');

return view('restaurant.categoryAdd',['myvar' => 'xxx']);
```

obs: I'm running XAMPP, and It's the only issue I had at this time.
 obs2: The problem is not the 'return view' method, It's just working. The problem is my view, It's not receiving the variable.

Comment: All seems fine. Do you have more views with camelCase? Might have something to do with this..

Comment: I changed the camelcase (categoryAdd to categoryadd) and it just works.

Comment: Thank you. I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

So try this:

In your controller:

```
public function formAdd() {
  $variable = 'Hello';
  return view('restaurant.categoryAdd')->with('myvar', $variable);
}
```

In your view (if HTML, simply):

```
<?php
 print $myvar; 
?>
```

Comment: Also try `return View::make('restaurant.categoryAdd')->with('myvar', $variable);`

Comment: Yes, in both cases if I turn error logs on I got: Undefined variable: myvar

Comment: ErrorException in 79f4f462613468cdd5a62ac56d14026eaddd8cdd.php line 8:
Undefined variable: myvar

Comment: ErrorException in 79f4f462613468cdd5a62ac56d14026eaddd8cdd.php line 8:
Undefined variable: myvar (View: /htdocs/Servido/resources/views/restaurant/categoryList.blade.php)

Comment: You're in the wrong blade from what I can see. Try the following: `return view('restaurant.categoryList')->with('myvar', $variable);` What this means is that in resources/views/ there is a folder called restaurant in which there is a file called categoryAdd.blade.php which means `resources/views/restaurant/categoryAdd.blade.php`, however the error you've posted is on categoryList.blade.php and not in categoryAdd.blade.php. Kindly check the view you want to use and mention that in the return path

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in camelcase. I changed the view to 'categoryadd' and It's working now.